# Retrieve all objects that have a column that does not equal to undefined

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

[image] 
I want to retrieve two objects with title `cc` and `bb` above.
My code:

```
var Item = Parse.Object.extend('Item');
var query = new Parse.Query(Item);
query.notEqualTo('parentItem',undefined);
query.find().then(function(subItems){
    console.log(subItems);
},function(error){
    console.log(error.code+': '+error.message);
});
```

The error is `102: pointer field parentItem needs a pointer value`
Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: Change `undefined` to `null` and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Parse.Query.exists(key)`

```
var Item = Parse.Object.extend('Item');
var query = new Parse.Query(Item);
query.exists('parentItem');
query.find().then(function(subItems){
   console.log(subItems);
},function(error){
   console.log(`${error.code}: ${error.message}`;
});
```

Comment: looks like exists is not supported anymore, see: 
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: query.exist is not a function

Comment: @sandr, Your answer is correct but you have a little error, please correct.

query.exists('parentItem') not query.exist('parentItem')

Answer (score 4):

Change undefined to null and it will work

```
var Item = Parse.Object.extend('Item');
var query = new Parse.Query(Item);
query.notEqualTo('parentItem',null);
query.find().then(function(subItems){
    console.log(subItems);
},function(error){
    console.log(error.code+': '+error.message);
});
```